# How to get the opening price of all NSE equities before the market close?

Tags: stocks, india, nse-india

NSE Bhavcopy (csv file with OLHC info of all the equities) are available [here](http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/cmbhav.htm). However, it is made available only after the market is closed. So, is there any way to get the open price of all NSE equities before the market close?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such option available for Public. The current file has opening as well as closing prices and hence can only be made available after markets close.

Comment: yup, but i dont need the bhavcopy. I want only the open price. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a personal finance question but I will try and answer it. As indicated Bhav Copy is only available after the market is closed. If you want it during the market is open, you have to write routines to get the prices by querying the NSE web site some 1500 times (once for each stock) programatically. There is of course another way of buying NSE feed for 12,00,000/- INR per year & querying that feed once.

So, choices are between wait for End of day, screen scrape NSE site 1500 times a day or pay 12,00,000/- INR/annum - thanks